# Pydantic set attributes with a default function

Tags: python, pydantic

Is it possible to pass function setters for immutable [Pydantic Models](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/).

For example:

```py
from uuid import uuid4, UUID
from pydantic import BaseModel
from datetime import datetime

def generate_uuid():
    return uuid4()

def get_datetimenow():
    return datetime.now()

class Item(BaseModel):

    class Config:
        allow_mutation = False
        extra = "forbid"

    id: UUID
    created_at: datetime
```

I want the methods `generate_uuid` and `get_datetimenow` to set the attributes.

```py
>>> Item()
ValidationError: 2 validation errors for Item
id
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
created_at
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

While I want to get an `Item` object with `id` and `created_at` automatically set. Identical result as when you run:

```py
>>> Item(id=generate_uuid(), created_at=get_datetimenow())
Item(id=UUID('8f898730-3fad-4ca9-9667-c090f62a2954'), created_at=datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 19, 21, 13, 7, 58051))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`default_factory`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/#fields-with-dynamic-default-values) parameter of `Field` with an arbitrary function. Like so:

```
from uuid import uuid4, UUID
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from datetime import datetime

class Item(BaseModel):

    class Config:
        allow_mutation = False
        extra = "forbid"

    id: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
    created_at: datetime = Field(default_factory=datetime.now)
```

Comment: what if the *function* is within the `Item` class? How can I refer to it?